# How to model NFTs for a game

Tags: nft, games

I am struggling to understand how the different pieces of an NFT game should work. I have some doubts about how many `ERC20`, `ERC721` and `ERC1155` should I create.

I want to create a game where users can own cars. Let's say there are only two different cars, a Ferrari and a Tesla. Which is the best way to handle this? One `ERC721` where I store a `struct` with the car's data (is Ferrari or Tesla)? One `ERC721` for each car type? One `ERC1155` with two different token types?

What if I want to keep track of how many tokens are for each one? I want to make sure that there is an exact probability of getting a Ferrari or a Tesla when you mint a new car.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I had to google what was the ERC715, and didn't find any relevant sources, did you mean ERC721 perhaps ?
From what I understand, ERC1155 would be enough for your use case (one id by car, then a capped amount of token of this car)

Comment: omg.. yes I mean ERC721. So ERC1155 with one token id per car type and I have to keep track of whatever ratio I want. I will give it a try!